# Creating a single parameter for all Junit tests

Tags: java, rest, junit, rest-assured

I couldn't think of a better title sorry.

I'm creating an automated api test for our website's sales flow (which has 4 steps). When you initiate the salesflow you are given a key that needs to be passed at each step of the sales flow.

I want to create a separate Junit test for each 4 steps. I've written a method the initiates and returns the key:

```
public String initiate_salesflow() throws Throwable {

       RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080";

        String res = given().

                when().
                get("/salesflow/initiate").
                then().
                contentType(ContentType.JSON).
                extract().
                path("stackId");

        return res;
```

I've created an instance variable to hold the key that's returned, and to create the url for other tests to use:

```
private String URL = "http://localhost:32768/salesflow/"+initiate_salesflow();
```

However every time each of my junit tests run the above method creates a new key, when I want them to all match. I understand @BeforeClass could run the method once however there is there a way of passing the returned value to the other tests?

Thanks

Comment: @Before and get a new key every test ?

Comment: Thanks, but the key needs to be the same for every test. It's how our salesflow recognises you're the same customer. If the key is different I can't confirm all the details are correct on the final step.

Comment: Declare your key as a class field, init its value in `@BeforeClass` and use in tests

Comment: @BeforeClass has to be void so I don't understand how I can't return any values to be used in other tests?

Answer (score 1):

Premise: **You want a single IDENTICAL key for all four of your tests, despite them being four different tests.**

With this statement in mind, I must point out that your four individual tests are not unit tests if they have to work together to complete a single business task. In other words, if any of the four steps fails, your business task has failed.

This is not suitable for `@Before` because that is used to set up each individual test, and if you test using something like JUnit, you will find that the Class may be reinstantiated for every single individual test, so even pre-assigning the variable may not work.

This is what you have described your situation as.

```
public class Test {
    private String testKey;

    private String generateKey() {
        return String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testKey = generateKey();
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println(testKey);
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println(testKey);
    }

    //... etc
}
```

What ends up happening is that each test ends up getting a new key, so testA's key and testB's key are different timestamps in this case.

`testKey` will never be the same for these two tests because the timestamp will change.

The solution is to extract the four individual steps into a single super-test.

```
public class Test {
    private String testKey;

    private String generateKey() {
        return String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        testKey = generateKey();
    }

    @Test
    public void superTest() {
        testA();
        testB();
        testC();
        //...
    }

    private void testA() {
        System.out.println(testKey);
    }

    private void testB() {
        System.out.println(testKey);
    }

    //... etc
}
```

Assuming your test fails if any of the four steps fails, `superTest` implementation will still fulfill the contract, as any `Assert.fail()` call will fail that test. If each individual test still can still work as a standalone unit, you can add the `@Test` notations back to them and remove the `private` signature.

If you are using a mocking framework like EasyMock, you may have to reset your mock status after every method call.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    private String key;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(){
      key = yourMethod();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
       // another test using the key
    }

}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.